# bifurcating the values basis bucket and count using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned three tables.

Table1:

```
ID         Ref_ID          category_id    Date
II-1       xrt-11-gt       1              2019-01-01 15:34:18
II-2       xtt-10-xt       1              2019-01-05 17:14:20
II-3       xyt-09-yu       2              2019-02-04 11:04:12
II-4       xet-12-ct       2              2019-02-01 12:33:14
```

Table2

```
Ref_ID2       Value
xrt-11-gt     150
xrt-11-gt     175
xrt-11-gt     165
xrt-11-gt     168
xtt-10-xt     200
xtt-10-xt     45
xyt-09-yu     34
xet-12-ct     78
```

Table3

```
ref        type
1          Active
2          InActive
3          Hold
```

I have a query, like

```
select a.ID,a.Date,b.Value,c.type from Table1 a
left join Table2 b on a.Ref_ID=b.Ref_ID2
left join Table3 c on a.category_id=c.ref;
```

which return me below mentioned output.

```
ID      Value      Type         Date
II-1    150        Active       2019-01-01 15:34:18
II-1    175        Active       2019-01-01 15:34:18
II-1    165        Active       2019-01-01 15:34:18
II-1    168        Active       2019-01-01 15:34:18
II-2    200        InActive     2019-01-05 17:14:20
II-2    45         InActive     2019-01-05 17:14:20
II-3    34         InActive     2019-02-04 11:04:12
II-4    78         InActive     2019-02-01 12:33:14
```

I need to convert the above output in the below mentioned format in MySQL itself.

Where, the `1-3` and `3-5` are the bifurcation of count of ID basis on the bucket it fall as per the `Type`.

```
Month       Total      Active  1-3   3-5   InActive   1-3   3-5  Hold  1-3  3-5
Jan-19       6           2      1     1       0         0    0     0    0    0
Feb-19       2           0      0     0       2         2    0     0    0    0
```

Comment: Ok i'm the first to ask what is column 1-3 and 3-5 and how you get the numbers? or simple what is the difference between does columns?

Comment: @nbk: That would be derived basis the count, suppose there are 3 count of particular id then it will fall in `1-3` and if there are 4 id it will fall `3-5` bucket.

Comment: @VectorJX Where do the `1-3` and `3-5` column come from? Or why are the columns `1-3` and `3-5` and not say... `1-8` and `9-40`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b-%y') month,
    COUNT(*) total,
    SUM(type = 'Active') active,
    CASE WHEN SUM(type = 'Active') BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN SUM(type = 'Active') ELSE 0 END `1-3`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(type = 'Active') BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN SUM(type = 'Active') ELSE 0 END `4-5`,
    SUM(type = 'InActive') inactive,
    CASE WHEN SUM(type = 'InActive') BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN SUM(type = 'InActive') ELSE 0 END `1-3`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(type = 'InActive') BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN SUM(type = 'InActive') ELSE 0 END `4-5`,
    SUM(type = 'Hold') hold,
    CASE WHEN SUM(type = 'Hold') BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN SUM(type = 'Hold') ELSE 0 END `1-3`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(type = 'Hold') BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN SUM(type = 'Hold') ELSE 0 END `4-5`
FROM 
    Table1 a
    LEFT JOIN Table2 b on a.Ref_ID=b.Ref_ID2
    LEFT JOIN Table3 c on a.category_id=c.ref
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b-%y');
```

Note that this will not return *exactly* what you are showing in your expected output. Especially, there will be a few differences in the first record, that is showing aggregated data for January: total will be 6 for that month, with 4 active. But this is what I understood from your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @nbk for fixing the typos!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but its not working fine by joining all three Tables in the same query. The bucket `1-3` and `3-5` returning value as 0. Also, the query is taking too much time to execute.